# Copy text without exiting copy mode

Tags: tmux

tmux's `copy-mode` offers the ability to scroll up through a window's history, visually select text, and copy it to the clipboard. As soon as text is copied, `copy-mode` exits and tmux returns to insert mode.

Quite often, I'll want to copy multiple pieces of text from the same area in quick succession. Since tmux exits `copy-mode` after each selection, I find myself scrolling back to the same page again and again.

Is there a way to prevent tmux from exiting `copy-mode` after `copy-selection` is executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `copy-selection -x`.

See [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/2x8meq/tmux_patch_to_copy_in_copy_mode_without_leaving/) for more details.